# Crafter CMS - Is there a way to link to another CMS document in RTE?

Tags: crafter-cms

I need to be able to link to another document on the site in the rich text editor by browsing and selecting it without manually typing in a URL to the document. Is this possible with Crafter?

I looked through the documentation about the RTE configuration plugins, and it looked like ***maybe*** the insert-component or insert-linkBrowse plugins would do it, but I made an attempt to configure them and add an item in the RTE editor controls, but it had no effect. I couldn't find any documentation specifically about those plugins, so everything I did was just a (wrong) guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing out-of-the-box that addresses this use-case. Options:

- Build your model such that it has a repeating group of item pickers after the RTE and then followed by another RTE if need be (this means it won't be inside the RTE), which would make things more structured and arguably cleaner
- Build it as a customization (it'll be a TinyMCE plugin)
- Wait for the feature to be built by Crafter CMS: https://github.com/craftercms/craftercms/issues/1412

Comment: The first option will not work since the data is not that structured. It's an article that can link to other pages anywhere in the text, but I may try option number 2 when I get a chance.